# serviceController return wrong status

Tags: .net, service, servicecontroller

```
            ServiceController serviceController = null;
            try
            {
                serviceController = new("name");

                serviceController.Refresh();

                if (serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                {
                    if (serviceController.StartType == ServiceStartMode.Disabled)
                    {

                    }

                    serviceController.Start();
                    serviceController.Refresh();
                    serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                    serviceController.Refresh();
                    var s = serviceController.Status;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

I am trying to start my service if found the service is stopped.
What I manually to make the service to stop is stop the service and delete a critical file, so then the service cannot be started.
And then code will be go into the if statement.
but after I did start() and WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running), it got running.
and if I change the call to WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped), it got stopped.
that is weird.
I am using .net 6.